# PHP MYSQL Turkish characters issue

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add some values to my mysql table,i can manually add turkish characters,however when i try it in php code by insert into it cuts the string when it face with turkish characters,

i give you a screenshoot of my database !
[image]

```
Here is my php code,

        $sql = "insert into emlaknet (phone,userInfo,category) values ('" . $k . "','" . $userName . "','" . $data["cat"] ."');";
            executeQuery($sql);




function executeQuery($sql){
    global $conn;
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         //echo "Query Executed success " . $sql . " <br>";
    } else {
        // echo "Query Executed Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: when i set it mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');
 there is a progress.
database become L?tfullah ?imen

Comment: What is the character set of your table. You should change it to fix this issue.